# Fastest way to retrieve a folder's content on Mac, in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Well, the title is quite explicit, but a little explantations for those interested in the background.
I'm developing a little image browser. On part of the application is a directory browser which allows me to browse all the folders of my hard drive and mounted volumes.
And while profiling, I noticed that the most time consuming method of my application was the following piece of code :

```
// get the content of the directory
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:mPath];
mCachedContent = [[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url
                               includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                               options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                               error:nil] retain];

// parse the content, count the number of images and directories.
for (NSURL * item in mCachedContent)
{
    if (CFURLHasDirectoryPath((CFURLRef)item))
    {
        ++mNumChildren;
    }
    else if ([FileUtils isImage:[item path]] == YES)
    {
        ++mNumImages;
    }
}
```

This is necessary so that the NSOutlineView can know if a directory is expandable (and the number of images is also a feature I need)
To be more precise, the most time consuming method if [NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL...]

So, is there any other way of getting a directory's content more efficient than the one I'm using ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: The way you are doing it seems fine.  If you wanted to improve the user experience, you could first get a list of files in the directory, sort through to find the images, then load them individually and display them as they are loaded, which will appear slightly faster to the user if you are doing what I think you are.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance, but two other options would be `FSGetCatalogInfoBulk` and `readdir()`

Comment: What is the `isImage:` method doing? Hopefully it's just using UTIs to determine file type and not reading the headers of every file it encounters.

Comment: thanks for the alternatives sbooth ! I'll definitely check that ^^ And isImage is only checking the filename's extension : I just read folder's content once with getContent...AtURL.

Comment: OK, i've found a little library named UKDirectoryEnumerator which is basically a wrapper around FS functions, and I did get any noticeable performance improvement. Thanks you all for your answers !

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you write this function (e.g. with either Cocoa's `NSFileManager` API or the Unix [`opendir(3)`/`readdir(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/opendir.3.html) API), it's going to be I/O-bound—you're going to spend more time waiting on I/O than on any CPU operations performed in the middle layers.

If this is truly your bottleneck, then that means you're doing way too much I/O.  Make sure you're not doing anything stupid like continually reading the contents of the same directory over and over again hundreds of times per second.  If you need to continually watch a particular directory and take action whenever something in that directory changes (e.g. a file gets written to, a file is created or deleted, etc.), then use the [File Systems Events API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  This allows you to efficiently respond to those events when they happen without having to continually poll the directory.

Comment: The problem is : I cant' reduce IO by design. The code is used by the items of a directory browser ... so I NEED to get a directory's content, to know at least how many subdirectory it has (and the number of images is a feature I added) I'm already doing as few IO as I can, but the following case is problematic : One folder with lots of subfolders. When you expand, the view ask for the children, and this is where I need to get the number of images and subfolders.

Comment: @Citron: How often is your function here getting called?  When you profiled it, how much time is being spent in the function itself?  How much time is being spent in each of `[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:...]`, `CFURLHasDirectoryPath()`, and `[FileUtils isImage:]`?

Comment: I'm at work, so I can't give you the exact number, but it was something like more thant 97% of the time spent in getContent...
CFURLHasDirectory() simply check for a trailing '/', since NSURL of directories are guaranteed to end with a '/' and isImage simply compare the extension of the filename with a list of supported ones.

As for the frequency, it's done once for each subdirectory. So, if a directory contains 1000 subdirectories, the snippet will be executed 1000 times before letting the UI update. This is why I need to speed this up as much as possible ^^